# Passing string as blittable type for UnmanagedCallersOnly native method

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

Trying to use the UnmanagedCallersOnly attribute but I'm stuck on some string fields in the structure. Is it possible to model this structure that is usable with the new UnmanagedCallersOnly attribute?

C++ structure:

```
struct PluginInfo {
        int     nStructSize;   
        int     nType;         
        int     nVersion;      
        char    szName[ 64 ];  
        char    szVendor[ 64 ];
};
```

I'm getting stuck on converting the szName and szVendor to c#.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct PluginInfo
{
    public int StructSize;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public PluginType Type; // PluginType is an enumeration

    public int Version;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 64)] //[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string Name;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 64)] //[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string Vendor;
}


public class Plugin
{
    [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvCdecl) })]
    public static void GetPluginInfo(ref PluginInfo pluginInfo)
    {

        pluginInfo.Name = "myPluginName";
        pluginInfo.Vendor = "myVendorName";
        pluginInfo.Type = PluginType.Data;
        pluginInfo.StructSize = Marshal.SizeOf((PluginInfo)pluginInfo);

    }
}
```

The error is **"Cannot use 'PluginInfo' as a parameter type on a method attributed with 'UnmanagedCallersOnly'"**

Comment: `UnmanagedType.ByValTStr` instead of `LPWStr`

Comment: @Charlieface Unfortunately, that gives me the same error.

Comment: You definitely need that anyway. `char[]` instead of `string` and `ByValArray`? I'm not sure `UnmanagedCallersOnly` is possible here at all

Comment: Still doesn't work. I may have to assume that it's not supported.

Comment: Needs to be blittable see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices#blittable-types) not sure why it's not working with a `char` array

Comment: `PluginInfo` isn't blittable (the `string`s). It must be marshaled, so the method that uses `PlugInfo` can't be `UnmanagedCallersOnly`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

unsafe struct PluginInfo
{
    public int nStructSize;
    public int nType;   
    public int nVersion;
    // fixed means in place buffer, like in your C++ declaration
    public fixed char szName[64];
    public fixed char szVendor[64];
};

class d{
    [UnmanagedCallersOnly(CallConvs = new[] { typeof(CallConvCdecl) })]
    unsafe public static void GetPluginInfo(PluginInfo* info)
    {
        // PluginInfo required to be blittable, so we can use sizeof directly
        Debug.Assert(Marshal.SizeOf<PluginInfo>() == sizeof(PluginInfo));
        info->nStructSize = sizeof(PluginInfo);

        // use Span
        var s = new Span<char>(info->szName, 64);
        "hello".CopyTo(s);
        s["hello".Length] = '\0'; // it's `sz`, so null terminator is required
        
        // or use pointer directly
        info->szName[0] = 'x';
    }

    unsafe static void Main()
    {
        delegate* unmanaged[Cdecl]<PluginInfo*, void> callback = &GetPluginInfo;

        PluginInfo inf = default; // zero initializedd, unless SkipLocalsInit applied
        callback(&inf);
        
        // copy to string
        var name = new string(inf.szName/*, 0, 64 - 1*/);
        // or use [ReadOnly]Span
        var name2 = MemoryMarshal.CreateReadOnlySpanFromNullTerminated(inf.szName);
        
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine(name2.SequenceEqual(name));
        Console.WriteLine(name2.SequenceEqual("xello"));
        Console.WriteLine(inf.nStructSize == (64 + 64) * sizeof(char) + sizeof(int) * 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've abandoned the project a while ago and will have to dig out the code to test it but I'll go ahead and accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Ceres added some comments. You can play with it on https://sharplab.io